# Must I set lifecycleOwner for a data binding in Android Studio?

Tags: android

`binding` is a data binding, I set the lifecycle owner to the lifecycle of the view.

Is it necessary ?

It seems that the app can work well if I remove `binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner`.

**Code**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {

   private lateinit var binding: LayoutHomeBinding

   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, R.layout.layout_home, container, false
        )

        // Set the lifecycle owner to the lifecycle of the view
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this.viewLifecycleOwner   //Must I set lifecycleOwner for a data binding?

        ...
   }

}
```

Comment: personally I never set it, and it always works fine. Maybe it is relevant when you declare `LiveData` variables directly in the layout? In the Fragments you need the `lifecycleOwner` to declare the observer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using a `LiveData` object with your binding class, it is required to set a lifecycle owner to define the scope of the `LiveData` object.

So if you have a `LiveData` object like:

```
private val _name = MutableLiveData("John")
val name: LiveData<String> = _name
```

And you use it for binding like:

```
android:text="@{vm.name}"
```

Then you need to specify a lifecycle owner.

Comment: What if I don't use LiveData but StateFlow?

Comment: @tsil Same for `StateFlow`.